# Folder or Folder Shortcut on Honeycomb 3.1 home screen

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

I have a Toshiba Thrive and want to have access to several files in a folder, but can not figure out how to do that without going through the effort of using File Manager?  Is there a way to do create a shortcut like you can do in Windows desktop?

Answer (score 1):

[ASTRO File Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro) can help you with this, just install it and run it once, then you can add folders by long-pressing the desktop, selecting More and tapping ASTRO. It will let you browse folders and one can be selected by long-pressing it.